# change pointer in std::unique_ptr without destroy it

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have C++ code that uses raw pointer with C functions `malloc`, `free` and `realloc`.

I am thinking to change it to smart pointer, but I really want to keep the `realloc` functionality, because I believe it is much better than `new`, since it does not need to "move" the contents every time.

How I can refactor this with `std::unique_ptr`?

Here is some pseudo code (I realize this code is not 100% safe. In fact I never tried to compile it)

```
class Demo{
   char *ptr;
   Demo(size_t size) : ptr( malloc(size) ){}

   bool resize(size_t size){
      char *ptr_new = realloc(ptr, size);

      if (ptr_new == nullptr){
         return false; // fail
      }

      // here is tricky part with std::unique_ptr,
      // ptr is already deleted...
      ptr = ptr_new;

      return true;
   }
};
```

Comment: Do you *really* need `realloc`? IMO a `std::vector` or similar dynamic containers are sooo much better.

Comment: I doubt that: " I believe it is much better than new, since it does not need to "move" the contents every time."

Comment: yes, I know vector is better. I wonder is this can be done with std::unique_ptr.

Comment: @DieterLücking of course realloc does not move every time. It often just extends the block and return same pointer address.

Comment: @Nick I'd say for your specific sample a you could assume `std::string` will be fairly optimized from its implementation already.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I always love your comments, but this time I do not understand what do you mean. I am sure there are some, probably old std::string implementations that are using malloc / realloc / free. In all cases, what I said is opinion-based and is not that much related to the question.

Comment: @Nick THX, I'm flabbergasted. What I wanted to say is that for the specific `char'` example I'd expect a fairly optimized implementation with `std::string` rather than `std::vector`. Take in account COW, and such mechanisms.

Comment: oh, no. real code is not for chars but for pod classes. this is what i came up as example.

Comment: How would you shrink memory usage with `std::vector`? I don't see any function that reduce the capacity of `vector` without copying or reallocating the whole memory block.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to reassign a pointer without deleting it is to use [`release()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release):

```
auto old_ptr = unique.release();
unique.reset(new_ptr);
```

So in your code that would be something like:

```
struct free_deleter {
    void operator(void* p) const { free(p); }
};

std::unique_ptr<char, free_deleter> ptr; // NB: malloc must be paired with free, not delete

bool resize(size_t size) {
    char* ptr_new = realloc(ptr.get(), size);
    if (!ptr_new) {
        return false;
    }

    ptr.release();
    ptr.reset(ptr_new); 
    return true;
}
```